# Multidimensional Prediction

Tags: python, machine-learning, prediction

I have a list of temporal series of values measured in different places. These measurements may or may not be correlated, (mostly depending on their relative positions, but it is plausible that some very close detectors would actually measure decorrelated series). I would like to predict the values of the whole set, taking into account the series of all of them and their correlation through time. If it is of any help, the values should also have relative periodicity

EDIT: I have access to the generated power of several solar panels. These solar panels are spread spatially, and I would like to use them as 'irradiance detectors'. Knowing the sun illumination in several places in the past, I wish to identify correlations in between signals, which could then be used to make predictions of illumination.
Regardless of usual patterns of production through a day (as seen on image), what I am interested in is the information I can extract from one pannels' past to predict another ones future.

I think I would need a Neural Network to solve this problem, but I am not sure how to feed it :I thought of using a temporal window and feed my NN with a few past values from A, B and C, but I am afraid it's a little weak.

The image shows an example of what my data I looks like.

How can I predict the next values of curve A knowing past values of A, B and C?

[image: example of sequences]

How to handle this prediction?

Comment: Cross-posted: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44285325/781723, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/76118/755, https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/27017/4274.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.

Comment: Sorry for that, I expected I would have a better chance to find help

Comment: The answer is 'It depends'.  It depends a lot on your problem domain and the nature of the quantity you are measuring -- we can't answer this in the abstract.  So, I encourage you to edit the question to describe the nature of where the time series comes from.  What is it measuring?  What patterns is it likely to have?  Do you have a model of how it evolves?

Comment: This question needs more help than we can provide. We like helping people, but sometimes you need to help yourself first by reading a book on the language, the on-line documentation, or asking someone you know. Once you understand the topic a little better, we invite you to edit this question, fix the obvious mistakes, and get it re-opened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to achieve this task is to use a RNN.

A good tutorial for learning how to develop such a neural network is here :
https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/recurrent

I also found this link, where they achieved training a RNN for a rather close problem :
http://blog.datatonic.com/2016/11/traffic-in-london-episode-ii-predicting.html

An even better inspiration : 
http://machinelearningmastery.com/time-series-prediction-lstm-recurrent-neural-networks-python-keras/

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way is to train 3 models with the same input but each will predict one value (A, B or C).

If you are sure about correlation between input variable and their impact on the predicted output, you may create one neural network with a common branch (probably RNN over the stacked 3 inputs) then 3 different prediction head where each will produce one prediction A or B or C. Fast-rcnn architecture is a great example of this.

Comment: My problem would be more having 3 Inputs and trying to predict one output. Mainly because I don't want to assert anything on the correlation between input variables